# How to go though the sheets of a Workbook with Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am a real newb programer trying to make a small java program that edits spreadsheets for a friend using Apache Poi. Currently I go through the excel file using this code:

```
Sheet paxgs = rs1.getSheetAt(0); 
for (Row row : paxgs) {
       Cell secCell = row.getCell(1);
       Cell firstCell = row.getCell(0);
       if (firstCell!=null && firstCell.getCellType()==firstCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
}
```

The problem is that I don't know the exact number of sheets that the excel file is going to have. I tried :

```
Workbook rs1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filename));    
for (Sheet sheet : rs1)
```

but it didn't work so I was wondering if there is any way to go through all the sheet of a workbook.

Comment: thanx a lot for the quick answer guys, both answers are rly helpful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `Workbook` doesn't implement `Iterable<Sheet>` like a `Sheet` implements `Iterable<Row>`, so you can't use an "enhanced" for loop.  But you can loop through the `Sheet` objects yourself, with a traditional for loop.  Use [`getNumberOfSheets()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getNumberOfSheets%28%29) to find the number of sheets, and [`getSheetAt`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getSheetAt%28int%29) to retrieve the individual `Sheet` objects.

```
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++)
{
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
    // Process your sheet here.
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but check this: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#sheetIterator()

Answer (score -1):

The workbook contains a protected field "_sheets" which is of type  java.util.List
so:-

```
 rs1._sheets.size();
```

Should get you the number of sheets. You should also be able to iterate through this list.

Comment: Protected fields are "protected" for some purpose; do not attempt to access them.